# Why does Grunt not add itself to the shell?

Tags: macos, gruntjs

I have a problem installing grunt. All the documentation, and blog post tutorials, say that running:

```
npm install -g grunt
```

will then allow you to run grunt commands from the terminal.

I have a situation where grunt appears to install with no errors, but typing the command grunt in the terminal still gives:

```
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

What could I be doing wrong? And where could I find grunt to add it to my BASH profile manually?

Comment: For what it's worth, Node is at 0.8.8

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Since Grunt version 0.4 (which was released 1 or 2 weeks ago) you need to install the grunt command line tool globally (if needed, use `sudo` before the command):

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

In your project location you then install the latest **grunt** version:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Option `--save-dev` will save the `npm` config in your **package.json** file, which makes it easier to install or reinstall the dependencies (using just `npm install`).

Comment: Worth noting that `grunt-cli` does not require global install. `npm install grunt-cli --save-dev` will do.  Then run per-project node commands by adjusting PATH as usual, e.g., `PATH=${PATH}:$(npm bin) grunt serve`.

Answer (score 13):

Try running the install with the verbose flag:

```
npm install -g grunt --verbose
```

You can see where it is being installed (something like /usr/local/share/npm/bin/grunt).  Then check your path:

```
echo $PATH
```

If the path does not contain the install bin location, modify the path in your bash profile to include the location of the bin directory, then try grunt again in a fresh terminal.

**UPDATE**: Grunt 0.4 altered installation process. For 0.4 installs, see answer from asgoth below.

Comment: So these paths came up in the install:

/usr/local/share/npm/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt

I tried adding them both, seperately to the bash_profile, but neither of them gave me the grunt command.

Comment: I would think adding /usr/local/share/npm/bin to your path would make it work.  Can you run grunt by invoking it with the full path, like "/usr/local/share/npm/bin/grunt"?

Comment: This workaround is appreciated, but it does not answer the actual question "Why does Grunt not add itself to the shell?".

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer; see "sudo nom install -g grunt-cli" answer below.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `grunt` in the current version `0.4.0` does not install a bin command. The last `0.3.x` version is `0.3.17`, which supports a bin command.  To run grunt from the command line, you will want to install the grunt command line grunt-cli:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli --verbose
```

Answer (score 6):

I had *installed node using Homebrew* and this was my solution:

- set config for -g (GLOBAL) install directory directory: **npm config
  set prefix /Users/YOURNAME/.node/**
- make sure to edit PATH: **sudo nano ~/.profile**
- add to path: **export PATH=“/Users/YOURNAME/.node/bin:”$PATH**
- then update source: **source ~/.profile**

Following these steps will allow any packages installed using *npm install -g somePKG* to be placed in the correct location regardless of your current working directory. And by updating your $PATH correctly command line functions will work.

Information based on:
Fixing npm permissions - bit.ly/1CmIyqx

Comment: This was the solution for my problem. When upgrading to the latest Node (via Brew) all global installed modules couldn't be resolved. Even after uninstalling from Brew and installing via the Node JS installer. Thanks!